# "This advice advises no methods" with AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj

I'm trying to use AspectJ after learning a bit of theory about it.

I've made a very basic example that was expected to work but I get, next to my method, the "This advice advises no methods" information message.

My code is the following:

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Object.class);

@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.ecc.bo.company.Company.getName(..))", returning = "x")
public void logResult(Object x) {
    logger.error("WITH ASPECTS, method returned: " + x.toString());
}
}
```

I can't really understand why, since the package name was being auto-completed when I was typing. Plus, I've put a breakpoint on the said method just in case (getName), and it indeed gets called.

Maybe did I miss some configuration step or maybe is there a syntax error I can't find ?

I've also tried with the ultra generic version with

```
execution(* *(..))
```

but it still doesn't seem to match with any method.

EDIT: here is the "interesting" part of the Company class:

```
public class Company {
  private String name;
  public String getName() {
   return name;
  }
}
```

There are no particular annotations, at least nothing related to AspectJ

Comment: it could be helpful to see the Company class aswell

Comment: Indeed, maybe there is missing code here. I really don't know if I should edit anything in my existing classes (I supposed that no, since the goal of AOP was, to me, to add something around my existing stuff).

Comment: Let us clarify few things first: Are you really using AspectJ (not Spring AOP)? Are you using compile-time or load-time weaving? How do you build your product (direct _ajc_ call from the command line, some IDE mechanism, AspectJ Maven plugin, anything else)? Also, please edit the question so as to provide a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with package names and imports.

Answer (score 0):

use this in xml
 
spring default proxy is jdk proxy can only be used for classes implement interface ;
you can use cglib , another proxy that can be used for plain class

Comment: " <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>'' to open

Comment: Welcome to SO, please edit your answer and put your comment within your original answer's body and delete the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Think problem can be in dots getName(..) in pointcut, dots means method get something, and in your code we can see getName() which do not have any vars, delete dots or set some var in method.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).